# Upgrade Flutter version in project

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to upgrade Flutter version in my project from `2.8.0` to `3.7.0`. If I got it right flutter should be using the default version installed on my machine, but it doesn't.  See commands below.

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 9944297138 (4 days ago) • 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
Engine • revision 248290d6d5
Tools • Dart 2.19.2 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

Still it tries to use previous version

```
flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in xxx...
Resolving dependencies...
Because xxx depends on flutter >=3.0.0 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
pub get failed
command: "/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.0/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin/dart __deprecated_pub --color
--directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "/usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.8.0/flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "/Users/yyy/.pub-cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

Comment: Ok, found the solution. Have you tried turning it off and on again?
`brew uninstall flutter && brew install flutter`

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

if it repeats, maybe you could:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
```